# dompdf colspan not working properly

Tags: html

i would like to print a table as pdf with the following code it showing properly in browser [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJUtf.png) but when pdf generate structure alter the positions[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3aw5p.png).... i m using dompdf......

```
enter code here<table class="table table-bordered table-striped" border='1' style="border-collapse: collapse;width:100%">
            <tr>
                <td rowspan="4" style="font-weight: bold">Time</td>
                <td colspan="14" style="font-weight: bold;text-align: center">Type Of Accident</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="7" style="font-weight: bold;text-align: center">URBAN</td>
                <td colspan="7" style="font-weight: bold;text-align: center">RURAL</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td rowspan="2" style="font-weight: bold">F</td>
                <td rowspan="2" style="font-weight: bold">GI</td>
                <td rowspan="2" style="font-weight: bold">MI</td>
                <td rowspan="2" style="font-weight: bold">NI</td>
                <td rowspan="2" style="font-weight: bold;text-align: center">Total Number of Accidents</td>
                <td colspan="2" style="font-weight: bold;text-align: center">No. Of Persons</td>
                <td rowspan="2" style="font-weight: bold">F</td>
                <td rowspan="2" style="font-weight: bold">GI</td>
                <td rowspan="2" style="font-weight: bold">MI</td>
                <td rowspan="2" style="font-weight: bold">NI</td>
                <td rowspan="2" style="font-weight: bold;text-align: center">Total Number of Accidents</td>
                <td colspan="2" style="font-weight: bold;text-align: center">No. Of Persons</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="font-weight: bold">Killed</td>
                <td style="font-weight: bold">Injury</td>
                <td style="font-weight: bold">Killed</td>
                <td style="font-weight: bold">Injury</td>
            </tr></table>
```

Answer (score -3):

I can not understand whats' you problem? If you thinking to print of table ctrl+p is be fine in windows machine browser.

Comment: i can generate a table using above code[refer to 1st image attach in context]..... but when i put these code on dompdf(css to pdf generator), the structure change[refer to 2nd image attach in context].......